# Ship overlapping in battleships python game

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

I am creating the battleships game in python where a player plays against a computer who has randomly placed ships in a 10x10 board.
The placement of the ships works fine but once in a while the ships overlap. 
No matter what I do, it will not stop overlapping the ships.

Here is the code:
    EDITED

```
ships = {'A': 5, 'B': 4, 'C': 3, 'S': 3, 'D': 2}
comp_board = []
for i in range(10):
comp_board.append([])
  for j in range(10):
   comp_board[i].append('.')

def print_computer_board(comp_board):
 for i in comp_board:
   print(' '.join(i))

def comp_place_ships(comp_board, ships):
  for key, value in ships.items():
    ship_not_placed = True
    while ship_not_placed:
     ori = random.randint(0,1)


    if ori == 0:
      x = random.randint(0,9-value)
      y = random.randint(0,9)
      placement = comp_board[x][y]
      if placement == '.':
        for ship in range(value):
          comp_board[x][y] = key
          comp_board[x+ship][y] = key
          ship_not_placed = False

    elif ori == 1:
      x = random.randint(0,9)
      y = random.randint(0,9-value)
      placement = comp_board[x][y]
      if placement == '.':
        for ship in range(value):
          comp_board[x][y] = key
          comp_board[x][y+ship] = key 
          ship_not_placed = False

    elif ori != 0 or 1 and placement != '.':
      print('Invalid choice, please try again.')
comp_place_ships(comp_board, ships)
print_computer_board(comp_board)
```

I tried using placement = comp_board[x+ship][y] and placement_hort = comp_board[x][y+ship] instead of placement = comp_board[x][y] to check if the placement is valid, but then I get a error: local variable "ship" referenced before assignment.

Do anybody have an idea on how to solve this? I've tried creating this game for a long while now and no matter what I do, I end up with one problem after another.

Comment: Your code is not complete. How is comp_board defined? How is ships defined?

Comment: I've edited the code now so both comp_board and ships are included + definition for printing the computer board.

Comment: Is  `if placement == '.'` your current overlap check ?  so you're only checking the first cell for overlaps, not every cell...  you need to check for non-overlapping rectangles.  Maybe you should hold the position of each ship in a list, and check against that, not against the 'board'?

Answer (score 0):

As JeffUK mentions, it looks like you are checking if the ends of a new ship intersect with an existing ship, but not if the middle parts do.

So you need to write two loops: one to check for intersections, and one to write out the new square on the grid.

```
any_intersections = False
if ori == 0:
  x = random.randint(0,9-value)
  y = random.randint(0,9)
  for z in range(y, y+value):
    if comp_board[x][z] != '.': any_intersections = True
  if not any_intersections:
    for ship in range(value):
      comp_board[x][y] = key
      comp_board[x+ship][y] = key

.... (ori = 1 is similar. I'll leave it as an exercise.)

if not any_intersections: print("Random allocation failed.")
return any_intersections
```

It also seems more flexible to have a function to place a ship e.g.

```
def place_ship(comp_board, ship_size):
  ori = random.randint(0,1)
  if ori == 0:
    x = random.randint(0,9-value)
    y = random.randint(0,9) #note: we could set a constant board_size = 10 and then range from 0 to board_size - 1 and board_size - 1 - value
    for z in range(y, y+value):
      if comp_board[x][z] != '.': return False
    for z in range(y, y+value): comp_board[x][z] = key
    return True
```

Then a more general place_ships function could run as following. I added some error checking, which you shouldn't need, but if you wanted to resize the board, maybe it would be interesting:

```
def place_ships(ship_list):
  for ship in ship_list:
    count = 0
    while not place_ship(comp_board, ship.size()):
      count += 1
      if count = 100:
        print("Bailing. Failed 100 times to place ship.")
        exit()
```